# fractionnal integral python

Tags: python, scipy, integral

I'm trying to compute the triple integral of the function `abs(x-y)**(H-1)*abs(y-z)**(H-1)*abs(z-x)**(H-1)`
on `[0,1]^3` for example with a H between `(0.5,1)`, However it seems hard for python to compute it.

So, firstly, i tried with integrate.tplquad from scipy but it's enable to do it, it only returns that the integral is probably divergent or slowly convergent.

To avoid this,I recode a Riemann function by the well-known method and I took an "epsilon" which is a small postive number such as 10**-6 in the function itself in every absolute value, but it's also necessary to take another epsilon on the interval
The first error, i noticed is that 0.0 cannot be raised to a negative power. But then doing that transformation, knowing the answer should be around 29.7, Python returns incompatible value.

I think the problem deals with numeric issue, or the integration scheme itself, although my function Riemann isn't otptimized, i think it should have been close to the real value I expected.

Here's the code

```
def f(H):
    eps=10**-12
    return lambda x,y,z:(abs(x-y)+eps)**(H-1)*abs(y-z+eps)**(H-1)*abs(z-x+eps)**(H-1)

def riemann(H,g,a,b,c,d,e,h,n):
    s=0
    du=(b-a)/n
    dv=(c-d)/n
    dw=(e-h)/n
    for i in range (n):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(n):
                s+=g(du*i,dv*j,dw*k)
    s=s/(n**3)
    return s
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you also provide an example call and for that call show what you got and what you expected to get.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what I expect is taken from a math article where they compute cumulants for a type of random variable, which is a Rosenblatt variable This is the triple integral which does appear in the third cumulant. The closer expression I get is about 27 but I don't remember the epsilons I took. When I play with these "epsilon"  and the eps in function f is 10**-12 with riemann(0,f(0.75),0,1,10**-12,1,10**-12,1,200) I obtained 132.22. It's obviously false and the parmater involved a lot with the result.

Comment: Hi! You can use the edit feature to update your original post so that this example is included. I am not up to par with the math you are talking about, but hopefully someone else can help you! I did try to run it a few times to see what kind of values you are getting and how the code works. Didn't really get anywhere, but I think the epsilon you used when you got  'about 27' is 10**-11 which gives `27.036095803564766`. Good luck!